# When encountering an onbeforeunload alert dialog while automating tests with gauge the test freezes

Tags: getgauge

While automating a test using Gauge I have found that when I encounter an alert triggered by an window.onbeforeunload the test the execution of the test halts.  The dialog text is:
Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved. "Leave" or "Cancel" buttons.

I have tried to solve this using the following:

```
1 - new Actions(DriverFactory.Driver).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
2 - DriverFactory.Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
3 - sending keys to the body SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

No matter what I try the following error comes up:

unexpected alert open

Even with a gauge message immediately after the backpage command it does not show on the report when gauge fails the test.
Gauge execution appears to completely stop when the dialog comes up.

Comment: I guess this is more of your driver and less of gauge's concern. `2` should work for webdriver, but you need to invoke it when the alert is present. If there is a sample code you can share, I can try and propose a solution.

Comment: I believe that you are correct.  The driver was having issues executing the following code when the alert was open:
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
If I used buttons in the application, the driver did not hang and I was able to interact with the alert at that point.  Thank You for the comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are correct.  The driver was having issues executing the following code when the alert was open:
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
If I used buttons in the application, the driver did not hang and I was able to interact with the alert at that point.  Thank You for the comment.